# How to make a button with a relief effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to achieve a relief effect of a button, I have the png file and I want to paint it in flutter.

I have tried with a CustomPainter Class and I'm so close. What I need is to draw a RRect with only 3 sides (left, bottom, right) that I want black with blur and the top side wite with blur and alpha.

[image: Result of my work]

I paste the code I used below but also give you this [link at dart.dev](https://dartpad.dev/ff2e3adcfeabc1885c0f1409f4524ade) with the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Obtained"),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 200,
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: BorderPainter(),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Text("Wanted"),            
            Image(
                image: NetworkImage("http://www.monacosimone.com/newGame.png")
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const double _kRadius = 25;
const double _kBorderWidth = 10;

class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  BorderPainter();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rrectBorder =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Offset.zero & size, Radius.circular(_kRadius));
    final rrectShadow2 = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(Offset.zero & size,
        topLeft: Radius.circular(_kRadius),
        topRight: Radius.circular(_kRadius),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_kRadius),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(_kRadius));
    final rrectShadow3 = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(Offset.zero & size,
        topLeft: Radius.circular(_kRadius),
        topRight: Radius.circular(_kRadius),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(_kRadius),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(_kRadius));

    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = _kBorderWidth
      ..color = Color(0xFFE6E6E6)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final shadowPaint2 = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = _kBorderWidth
      ..color = Color(0x55ffffff)
      ..strokeWidth = 50
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 10);

    final shadowPaint3 = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = _kBorderWidth
      ..color = Color(0x55000000)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 50
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.solid, 8);

    final borderPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = _kBorderWidth
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawRRect(rrectBorder, backgroundPaint);
    canvas.drawRRect(rrectBorder, borderPaint);
    canvas.drawRRect(rrectShadow2, shadowPaint2);
    canvas.drawRRect(rrectShadow3, shadowPaint3);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, I've been able to do this by my self, below my solution if it can be helpful for someone else.

[Solution](https://dartpad.dev/ff2e3adcfeabc1885c0f1409f4524ade)

[image]